# Creating a UTF8 text file instead of ANSI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I have this snippet of code to write a file asynchronously:

```
    private static async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
    { //Writes to our output files
        byte[] encodedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
            bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
            await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
        };
    }
```

The created text file is still ANSI format despite having set the `Encoding.UTF8`.  There's 15 overloaded constructors for the `FileStream` class, and it's not obvious at all to me where I should set this if not on the encoded text.

I can tell the file is ANSI, because when I open it in TextPad and view the file statistics it lists ANSI as the Code Set:

[image]

Having problems, because MySQL `LOAD INFILE` is not reading the file properly, after reading the answers I believe it has something to do with the BOM, but not sure.

I tried this (for BOM):

```
        byte[] encodedText = new byte[] { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF }.Concat(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)).ToArray();
        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
            bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
            await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
        };
```

Textpad then saw it as UTF8, MySQL `LOAD INFILE` still failed.  Resaved in Textpad, and MySQL saw it properly.

Changed code to this:

```
        using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(filePath))
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync(text);
        }
```

This seemed to work in both.  I'm not sure what the issue is with MySQL `LOAD INFILE` regarding this.

Comment: Re your edit: textpad can't **tell** it is UTF-8 unless there is either a BOM, or characters above 127. ASCII, ANSI and UTF-8 are ***all 100% identical*** if all the characters are in the 0-127 range (assuming no BOM)

Answer (score 4):

No, it is definitely UTF-8:

```
byte[] encodedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

That can **only** give you UTF-8; you then write `encodedText` to the stream.

However! UTF-8 will look identical to ASCII/ANSI for any characters in the 0-127 range. It only looks different above that. False positive?

Comment: When I open it in textpad it lists it as ANSI, and MySQL 'load infile' complains.  If I resave it as UTF8 in textpad it fixes the MySQL issue.  So somehow this C# isn't creating a genuine UTF8 file.

Comment: @user17753 see my comment on the question. If the real issue is that MySQL demands a BOM, then that is a separate concern: however, a BOM is not a *requirement*, and it is still a valid UTF-8 file without a BOM.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you forget to write [BOM header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the beginning of the file. As you are using FileStream (and not some sort of TextWriter) you have to write it manually.
In case of UTF-8 it should be "EF BB BF"

Comment: The BOM doesn't change the encoding of the file, just how *some* text editors will open it.

Comment: A BOM is not a strict necessity, really. Nice to have, maybe - but it also risks bad clients misunderstanding the first few bytes, even if the rest of the data is pure ASCII.